# Java - regex to get value from first number

Tags: java, regex

I have the following requirement.
I have a String `"BL req 12345/67890"`, "`BL/1234/67890"`

I need to get `"12345/67890"`, `"1234/67890"`
To extract value from first number

Can anyone please share the regex for this scenario using java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
[A-Za-z\\s]|(?<=[A-Za-z\\s])/
```

Here's an example:

```
String pattern = "[A-Za-z\\s]|(?<=[A-Za-z\\s])/";
String s = "BL req 12345/67890";
String s1 = "BL/1234/67890";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Darshan

Answer (score 4):

This will work provided that at least one digit is presented before and after `/`

```
[0-9]+[\/][0-9]+
```

[try it here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

A bit messy but worth the try and straight forward, here it goes:

```
public class test {
    private test(){
String firstresult  = "BL req 12345/67890";
String output1 = (firstresult.split("q",2)[1]);

String secondresult = "BL/1234/67890";
String output2 =  (secondresult.split("/",2)[1]);

System.out.println(output1);
System.out.println(output2);
    }
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new test();
}
}
```

Tested.